# Use referenced table field as an argument for GraphQL schema in Laravel Lighthouse

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I am using [nuwave/lighthouse](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/) with Laravel to create a GraphQL API and I have the below two tables

```
Authors
----------
id
username
name


Articles
--------
id
author_id
title
```

I can get a list of Articles that belongs to an Author by `author_id` with below schema

```
type Query {
    articles(author_id: Int! @eq): Article @all
 }

type Author {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
    name: String!
    articles: [Article!]! @hasMany
}

type Article {
    id: ID!
    author_id: ID!
    title: String!
    author: Author! @belongsTo
}
```

The query would be

```
{
    articles(author_id: 1) {
        data {
            title
        }
    }
}
```

I have the two Eloquent models with relationships defined properly.

What I can't figure out is how to get a list of Articles by the `username` of the Author. The query should look like below

```
{
    articles(username: "joebloggs") {
        data {
            title
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing anyone who isn't familiar with Laravel but know GraphQL still would be able to help me by referring to the [Lighthouse Directives](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html)

Comment: I'll recommend you to look at `hasOne` directive and use the scope argument on that directive to filter by username.

Comment: @OliverNybroe I went a bit further with setting up the scope in the Model. It's a dynamic scope and which accepts `username`. I could not find any reference on how to define a dynamic scope in the schema. Any tips on this?

Comment: Try take a look at the `builder` directive. With that method you get access to your query builder and your argument and can define all your custom logic for it. Then you can just do as you normally would in Laravel.

Comment: Another approach would be to use the `where` directive and define the `clause` parameter. Then you just set the clause parameter to the name of your scope which filters by username and that scope will get the value as it's argument.

Comment: I've got the '@builder' to work. I'll post the answer to benefit anyone who have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get this working after following the suggestion from @OliverNybroe

Added the `belongsToAuthor` method to the `Article` model

```
public function belongsToAuthor($builder, $username)
{
    return $builder->where('id', 
        Author::where('username', $username)->first()->id
    );
}
```

Query in the schema looks like

```
articles(username: String! @builder (method: "App\\Article@belongsToAuthor")): [Article!]! @paginate(type: "paginator" model: "App\\Article")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Lighthouse we normally use `eq` directive for this, but I'm your case you are trying to do a where statement from a field on a relationship.

You can do this with several approaches, the most flexible is the [`builder` directive](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#builder). This directive let's you modify the query builder in a method from a graphql argument. In the method it passes the query builder and argument values as the method arguments. You can then easily in this method do the where statement you need to filter by username.

Another approach would be to use the [`where` directive](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#where) together with the `clause` argument. Then the value you would supply in the `clause` argument would be a scope which filters by username. This scope would get the dynamic value entered in the graphql argument supplied.

The logic to filter would be the same in both approaches and would look something like the following

```
$articlesQuery->whereHas('author' function (Builder $query) use ($username) {
    $query->where('username', '=', $username);
});
```